# Adding a class based on a value (jquery)

Tags: jquery, class, select

I have a little problem with the following piece of code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var val = $(this).attr("value");
            if(val){
                $(".place").not("." + val).hide();
                $("." + val).show();
            } else{
                $(".place").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

I want to adapt the code because there is a value that has spaces in it and so it doesn't work for this one.
The value that doesn't work has 2 spaces in it: "Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)" (that's the exact name). The other values have no spaces.

```
<select tabindex="" id="Antenne" name="Antenne" class="fusion-form-input" data-holds-private-data="false">
<option value="Antibes">Antibes</option>
<option value="Biot">Biot</option>
<option value="Châteauneuf-Grasse">Châteauneuf-Grasse</option>
<option value="Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)">Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)</option>
<option value="Valbonne">Valbonne</option><option value="Vallauris">Vallauris</option>
<option value="Villeneuve-Loubet">Villeneuve-Loubet</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered the spaces within the class attribute means its interpreted as multiple separate classes instead of a single one, so you cannot select by it.

To work around this you can use `data` attributes on the target elements, along with `filter()` to retrieve them, like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $places = $('.place');

  $("select").on('change', function() {
    let val = $(this).val();    
    $places.hide().filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('loc') === val;
    }).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.place { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select tabindex="" id="Antenne" name="Antenne" class="fusion-form-input" data-holds-private-data="false">
  <option value="Antibes">Antibes</option>
  <option value="Biot">Biot</option>
  <option value="Châteauneuf-Grasse">Châteauneuf-Grasse</option>
  <option value="Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)">Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)</option>
  <option value="Valbonne">Valbonne</option>
  <option value="Vallauris">Vallauris</option>
  <option value="Villeneuve-Loubet">Villeneuve-Loubet</option>
</select>

<div data-loc="Antibes" class="place">Antibes</div>
<div data-loc="Biot" class="place">Biot</div>
<div data-loc="Châteauneuf-Grasse" class="place">Châteauneuf-Grasse</div>
<div data-loc="Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)" class="place">Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)</div>
<div data-loc="Valbonne" class="place">Valbonne</div>
<div data-loc="Vallauris" class="place">Vallauris</div>
<div data-loc="Villeneuve-Loubet" class="place">Villeneuve-Loubet</div>
```

Note in the above example the use of jQuery 3.6.0, which is the latest version as of this answer. 1.12.4 is outdated and needs to be updated.

Also, note that you can retrieve the selected value of the `select` using `val()` directly, without needing to loop through all the `option:selected` elements.

Comment: This works perfectly well for your example. The problem is that I use the Avada theme on Wordpress and I can only touch the ID or class for a container.

Comment: In that case you could use an 'attribute contains' selector on the class (`$places.hide().filter(`[class*="${val}"]`).show();`) however `Antibes` would also match `Garantie Jeunes (Antibes)` in this case. Unless you can edit the theme, there's not a lot more you can do.

Comment: What if I get around my problem of a space in the name with a blank character? I don't know if that would work.

Comment: Yep, that would work, however doing that implies that you can edit the theme...?

Comment: Okay, I've solved my problem! In the drop-down list of choices you could play with the label. So the label is Garantie Jeunes Antibes and that's what is displayed. The value is hidden and well taken into account by the code.